# How can I call table from button's listener?

Tags: extjs, ext.net

I'm creating screens from visual studio 2010 and i'm using ext.net.

I can call the table from grid panel but I need a function for button.
I have a store and modelfield names for  gonderimTipi and konu values. pnlDetay panel for my table.

```
        <ext:XTemplate ID="BookTpl" runat="server"> 
          <Html>
        <div id="mydiv" class="CSSTableGenerator">
            <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gönderim Tipi</td>
          <td>{gonderimTipi}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Konu</td>
          <td>{konu}</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        </table>
        </div>
          </Html>
           </ext:XTemplate>
                 <ext:ResourceManager ID="ResourceManagerAna" runat="server" />
            <ext:FormPanel ID="formPanelNorth" runat="server" BodyPadding="6" Frame="true">
             <Items>
            <ext:FieldContainer ID="fcAna" runat="server" Layout="HBoxLayout">
            <Items>
                <ext:TextField ID="txtAra" runat="server" Width="200" PaddingSpec="0 5 0 5" />
                <ext:Button ID="btnAra" runat="server" Text="Ara" UI="Primary" Icon="Magnifier">
                    <Listeners>
                        <Click Handler="#{BookTpl}.overwrite(#{pnlDetay}.show();" />
                        <Click Handler="App.pnlDilekce.show(); " />
                       </Listeners>
                </ext:Button>
                  </Items>
                </ext:FieldContainer>
               </Items>
             </ext:FormPanel>
            <ext:Panel ID="pnlDilekce" runat="server" Hidden="true">
              <Items>
        <ext:Panel ID="pnlDilekceOzet" runat="server" Resizable="true" ResizeHandles="South"
            Title="Dilekçe Özeti" TitleAlign="Center" Height="100" Flex="1" />
        <ext:Panel ID="pnldilekceIcerik" runat="server" Resizable="true" ResizeHandles="South"
            Title="Dilekçe İçerik" TitleAlign="Center" Height="100" Flex="1" />
        <ext:Panel ID="pnlDetay" runat="server" Height="400" Flex="1" BodyPadding="7" 
        BodyStyle="background: #ffffff;">
        </ext:Panel>
        </Items>
        </ext:Panel>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly problem are you facing with applying that on buttons? In other words, what exactly do you mean under "call table from button's listener"? I don't quite understand.

Comment: Hi @DaniilVeriga , I want to brought table to screen when I click the button. I made it with gridpanel before. I mean when I select a gridpanel item the table come. I will edit my question and put my full code up there.

Comment: At a minimum, there should not be two or more Click listeners defined in the markup. Please put two Handlers into one. Also, I guess, the first Handler contains a JavaScript syntax error(s).